# What is the difference between json.dumps() and JSONRenderer.render() methods?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am learning Django Rest Framework.
I came up across method JSONRenderer.render() which takes python objects and converts them to JSON string.

But why do not we use json.dumps() method for this.
Why to create another method which does the same work?

Comment: Did you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/fd8adb32cec9c7545039f03cc3aa6cda95d4d692/rest_framework/renderers.py#L52-L109)? It _uses_ `json.dumps`, and adapts it to the renderer interface.

Answer (score 1):

[json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) is a standard library function that converts a dictionary into a JSON string.

[JSONRenderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer) is a Django REST Framework [renderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/). Renderer is a class responsible for making sure your clients get a correctly-formatted [HTTP response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#http_responses). That is, that the response is a valid HTTP response, with a correct [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and other things like that. DRF allows you to use different renderers, because you might as well have sent an XML response, or a binary. All of them need to be formatted into a correct HTTP response.

`JSONRenderer` does need to convert a dictionary to JSON in order to fulfil its purpose, but that's not all it does. This class is aware that it's used in an HTTP context, while `json.dumps` is a generic function that purposely lacks this context so you could use it everywhere.